# Handling empty arrays in pySpark (optional binary element (UTF8) is not a group)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json-like structure in spark which looks as follows:

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet(good_partition_path)
id: string
some-array: array
    element: struct
        array-field-1: string
        array-field-2: string
```

depending on the partition, `some-array` might be an empty array for all `id`'s. When this happend spark infers the following schema:

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet(bad_partition_path)
id: string
some-array: array
    element: string
```

Of course that's a problem if I want to read multiple partitions because spark cannot merge schemas. I have tried to define manually the schema so there should be no problem

```
>>> df = spark.read.schema(good_schema).parquet(bad_partition_path)
id: string
some-array: array
    element: struct
        array-field-1: string
        array-field-2: string
```

So far so good, but when I try to actually collect the data I get an error:

```
>>> df.head(5)
# Long error message
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: optional binary element (UTF8) is not a group
```

I don't understand why this fails. There should be no incompatibility cause by the schema. In case you wonder, collecting the data without specifying the schema works.

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet(bad_partition_path)
id: string
some-array: array
    element: string   # infers wrong schema
>>> df.head(5)
[Row(...)] # actually works
```

## Edit

Here there's a reproducible example in python

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *


myschema = StructType([
   StructField('id', StringType())
 , StructField( 'some-array'
              , ArrayType(StructType([
                  StructField('array-field-1', StringType())
                , StructField('array-field-2', StringType())
                ])
              ))
  ])

path_writeKO = "path/to/parquet"
jsonKO = '{"id": "OK", "some-array": []}'
dfKO = sc.parallelize([jsonKO])
dfKO = spark.read.json(dfKO)
dfKO.write.parquet(path_writeKO) # write without schema

read_error = spark.read.schema(myschema).parquet(path_writeKO) # read with schema
read_error.collect() # Fails!!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I've found is setting the option `dropFieldIfAllNull` to `True` when reading the json file. This causes field with empty array to disapear, making merging schema easier.

```
>>> jsonKO = '{"id": "OK", "some-array": []}'
>>> dfKO = sc.parallelize([jsonKO])
>>> dfKO = spark.read.option('dropFieldIfAllNull', True).json(dfKO)
id:string
```

Now, undesired type inference won't apply and when reading multiple partitions of the same file the option `mergeSchema` will be able to read all files without colision.

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Thanks!. sorry for accepting your anwser and then step back :/

Comment: Nothing to care about since you found what you were looking for. Although I am not sure if the schema will be automatically merged by spark and extended to the one containing all the required information. Did you try it out?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I did try out! When reading you need to set `mergeSchema` option. This wouldn't work before because schemas were incompatible, but with this aproach missing columns will be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course that's a problem if I want to read multiple partitions
>   because spark cannot merge schemas. I have tried to define manually
>   the schema so there should be no problem

I am afraid that there is no such a schema which can parse simultaneously these two cases. The data `{"id": "OK", "some-array": [{"array-field-1":"f1", "array-field-2":"f2"}]}` can be parsed only with:

```
good_schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', StringType()), 
  StructField( 'some-array', 
              ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('array-field-1', StringType()),
                StructField('array-field-2', StringType())
              ])
          ))
  ])
```

when `{"id": "OK", "some-array": []}` with:

```
bad_schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', StringType()), 
  StructField('some-array', ArrayType(StringType()))
])
```

Therefore one option is to read these two directories with different schemas.

> I don't understand why this fails. There should be no incompatibility
>   cause by the schema.

As explained above the data is incompatible with the schema.

> In case you wonder, collecting the data without
>   specifying the schema works.

This is the expected behaviour since when there is no explicit schema specified Spark will try to discover it.

**Suggested solution**

The only solution that I can think of is to treat `some-array` field as a string. I don't know if this feasible in your system although you could implement it by `cast`ing the `some-array` into string for both schemas/partitions.

This conversion can be done with at least two options given:

```
good_data_df = spark.read.schema(good_schema).parquet(...)
bad_data_df = spark.read.schema(bad_schema).parquet(...)
```

1. Read both datasets and convert the `some-array` field to string then save the results under one common directory with:

```
good_data_df = good_data_df.withColumn("some-array", col("some-array").cast("string"))
bad_data_df = bad_data_df.withColumn("some-array", col("some-array").cast("string"))

good_data_df.union(bad_data_df).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("parquet_path")
```

2. Execute the above conversion in runtime skipping the re-write step.

Finally you can load `some-array` as a string and then convert it to `array_schema` using `from_json` function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

array_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('array-field-1', StringType()),
                StructField('array-field-2', StringType())]))

# we will use this for both partitions
generic_schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', StringType()), 
  StructField('some-array', StringType())
])

parquet_path = "/tmp/60297547/parquet"
good_data = "{'id': 'OK', 'some-array': \"[{'array-field-1':'f1a','array-field-2':'f2a'},{'array-field-1':'f1b','array-field-2':'f2b'}]\"}"
bad_data = "{'id': 'OK', 'some-array': '[]'}"

# putting bad and good partitions into the same dataset where some-array is string
rdd = sc.parallelize([bad_data, good_data])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet_path)

final_df = spark.read.schema(generic_schema).parquet(parquet_path)
final_df = final_df.withColumn("some-array", from_json(final_df["some-array"], array_schema))

final_df.show(10, False)

# +---+------------------------+
# |id |some-array              |
# +---+------------------------+
# |OK |[[f1a, f2a], [f1b, f2b]]|
# |OK |[]                      |
# +---+------------------------+

final_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- some-array: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- array-field-1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- array-field-2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless I still don't understand why `{"id": "OK", "some-array": []}` is parsed as `StructField('some-array', ArrayType(StringType()))`. I'd expect that spark wouldn't make any assumptions to the type of the elements.

Comment: This is a good question. Let me answer with an assumption that when an empty array is found Spark will convert it to array[string] by default.

Comment: @Ismor I believe though that the reason for that is that ArrayType will always require to specify a DataType, please take a look by yourself [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/293e5364e570e8a6569e47e58918db2f1d45ddff/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L280). The most generic DataType I can think of is StringType. That is because any other type can be converted into string (int, float, boolean all of them have a string representation). Therefore indeed it make sense to convert an empty array to array[string] by default.

Comment: I think so but then, why not leave the type as the general class `ArrayType(DataType)` since all spark types inherit from that once...

Comment: Because you can't DataType is abstract you must give a specific type which inherits DataType