# AWS Glue: An error occurred while calling o88.pyWriteDynamicFrame. optional binary context (UTF8) is not a group

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue job, reading from catalog (S3 parquet files) by using dynamic dataframe (since I want to use bookmark here),converting the dynamic dataframe to spark dataframe for later ETL process with other data frames (I removed this part currently for simple test) and write back to another S3 bucket. I keep getting the error like:
`An error occurred while calling o88.pyWriteDynamicFrame. optional binary context (UTF8) is not a group`

Can anyone please let me know what I'm missing. This error has driven me crazy since I have simplified my logic to minimum and still not working ... Thank you!

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,year,month,dayofmonth,to_date,from_unixtime

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
    

# dynamic reading from logs
src = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "logs", table_name = "parquet_all_regions_api_logs", transformation_ctx = "src")

dfApi = src.toDF()

# Suppose to have a whole bunch of ETL joins with other dataframes. Removed now for simplifying the logic

dynamicAPI = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dfApi, glueContext, "test_nest")

apiusage = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dynamicAPI, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://api-logs-usage/"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "apiusage")

job.commit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling empty arrays in pySpark (optional binary element (UTF8) is not a group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297547/handling-empty-arrays-in-pyspark-optional-binary-element-utf8-is-not-a-group)