# pyspark from_json is failing with error: Cannot parse the schema in JSON format: Unrecognized token 'array': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

`parquet_path = /tmp/test-parquet`

content of t2.json is:

```
{
   "id": "OK_good2", 
   "some-array": [
      {"array-field-1":"f1a","array-field-2":"f2a"},
      {"array-field-1":"f1b","array-field-2":"f2b"}
   ]
}
```

creating dataframe from `t2.json`

```
df = spark.read.json('t2.json')
df = df.withColumn('some-array', col('some-array').cast('string'))
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet_path)
```

formed schema from:

```
schema = dict(df.dtypes)['some-array'] # o/p array<struct<array-field-1:string,array-field-2:string>>
```

Reading from `parquet_path`:

```
final_df = spark.read.parquet(parquet_path)
final_df.select('some-array').show(3, False)
```

```
+------------------------+
|some-array              |
+------------------------+
|[{f1a, f2a}, {f1b, f2b}]|
+------------------------+
```

While trying to get the JSON schema of the same using `from_json` its failing. Im not able to figure out why. Please provide some help.

```
final_df.select(from_json(col('some-array'), 'array<struct<array-field-1:string,array-field-2:string>>', {'allowUnquotedFieldNames':True}).
                alias('json1')).show(2, False)
```

throws error:

```bash
AnalysisException: Cannot parse the schema in JSON format: Unrecognized token 'array': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"array<struct<array-field-1:string,array-field-2:string>>"; line: 1, column: 6]
Failed fallback parsing: Cannot parse the data type:
```

In case anyone interested i'm trying to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297547/handling-empty-arrays-in-pyspark-optional-binary-element-utf8-is-not-a-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues in your code.

1. You are losing key data from the JSON in this line.

```
df = df.withColumn('some-array', col('some-array').cast('string'))
```

So, when you are reading the parquet file that is saved, you only see this.

```
+------------------------+
|some-array              |
+------------------------+
|[{f1a, f2a}, {f1b, f2b}]|
+------------------------+
```

and NOT. (This is what you expect to have.)

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|some-array                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"array_field_1": "f1a", "array_field_2": "f2a"}, ...]|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

The proper way to cast the array structure to JSON string is to use `to_json`.

```py
df = df.withColumn('some-array', to_json('some-array'))
```

Please check `df.show()` or `df.take(1)` to see the difference.

2. Your DDL string needs wrapping with (`) for column name. (ref: https://vincent.doba.fr/posts/20211004_spark_data_description_language_for_defining_spark_schema/)

```py
'array<struct<`array-field-1`:string,`array-field-2`:string>>'
```

Comment: thanks @Emma for pointing out the details. This works for me.

Comment: @Emma It works thanks for giving all the details. :-)

Comment: @Emma any pointers as to why we don't get `json keys` even without casting the `some-array` column to `string` on df.show()

`
df = spark.read.json('t2.json')
df.show(5, False)
`
O/P
`
+--------+------------------------+
|id      |some-array              |
+--------+------------------------+
|OK_good2|[{f1a, f2a}, {f1b, f2b}]|
+--------+------------------------+
`

Comment: Try `df.printSchema()`.  If the `some-array` is array of struct, that how it is **displayed** on most of tools (without key value).  `printSchema()` should show the key name in this case.