# PySpark Cannot parse the schema in JSON format: Unrecognized token 'ArrayType': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

This is a follow up question from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297547/handling-empty-arrays-in-pyspark-optional-binary-element-utf8-is-not-a-group/72543129#72543129). @abiratis thanks for your answer, we are trying implement the same in our glue jobs,  the only change is that we don't have a static schema defined, so we have created a new column `colSchema` to hold the schema of each entry of `some-array`  attribute. Which looks like this:

```
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|some-array              |colSchema                                                                                                              |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{f1a, f2a}, {f1b, f2b}]|ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(array-field-1,StringType,true),StructField(array-field-2,StringType,true))),true)|
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But while converting it to json format using `from_json` i'm getting this error:

conversion is done this:

```
final_df.select(from_json(col('some-array'), 'ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(array-field-1,StringType,true),
StructField(array-field-2,StringType,true))),true)' {'allowUnquotedFieldNames':True}).alias('json1')).show(3, False)
```

Error is :

```
AnalysisException: Cannot parse the schema in JSON format: Unrecognized token 'ArrayType': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(array-field-1,StringType,true),StructField(array-field-2,StringType,true))),true)"; line: 1, column: 10]
Failed fallback parsing: Cannot parse the data type: 
mismatched input 'StructType' expecting INTEGER_VALUE(line 1, pos 10)

== SQL ==
ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(array-field-1,StringType,true),StructField(array-field-2,StringType,true))),true)
----------^^^
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the `from_json`'s [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html):

> schema: DataType or str
> a StructType or ArrayType of StructType to use when parsing the json column.
>
> Changed in version 2.3: the **DDL-formatted string** is also supported for schema.

The first parameter should be a json like column, which you have correct. The second parameter is either a DataType or a str **formatted  as  a [DDL string](https://vincent.doba.fr/posts/20211004_spark_data_description_language_for_defining_spark_schema/)**. This you got wrogn, since you are passing a DataType as a simple string. That isn't valid.

For your example, I think the correct definition would be simething like the following:

`` 'ARRAY<STRUCT<`array-field-1`: STRING, `array-field-2`: STRING>>' ``

Therefore,

```
final_df.select(from_json(col('some-array'), 'ARRAY<STRUCT<`array-field-1`: STRING, `array-field-2`: STRING>>')
```

should work

Comment: Thanks @Ismor, i have tested this works but have a new subsequent issue on this 1. how do we get the `DDL` for a **single** column in PySpark OR how can we leverage the schema obtained from `df.schema['some-array'].dataType` to be used?
I even tried getting the schema from `schema_of_json()` API but even thats not working. Please let me know if you come across any such solution. The issue is getting DDL for a single column is not working. I may have to do some hacks to get just the DDL for `some-array`

Comment: @user1119283 um.... I think you can't do it. Spark needs to know the schema before execution. There are some workarounds like `inferSchema` but those work only on reading files. A reason for this to not work is that if two rows have different schemas, the resulting dataframe would be inconsistent. Maybe using the `RDD` api reading everything as a bytestring could help. The workflow would be `read as bytestring rdd >> separate in multiple rdd each with the same schema >> convert each RDD in a different dataframe`. Any case, I think you can't avoid some non-trivial data manipulations.

Comment: Thanks @ismore for this flow will try out this.