# parquet nested structure error while reading from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have created a dataframe with a column:

```
StructType(List(StructField("shop",StringType),
StructField("items",ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField("id",StringType),StructField("qty",StringType),StructField("price",StringType)))))))
```

The data which I put for this schema is like:

```
Seq(Row("shop1",Array(Row("123","34","555"))))
```

I am writing this data in a parquet file.
Schema for this DF is:

```
shop: string
items: array
   element: struct
      id: string
      qty: string
      price: string
```

The data looks in dataframe show() command:

```
shop1 | [{123,34,555}]
```

When I am trying to read this file from another spark program, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: optional binary items (UTF8) is not a group
```

Can anyone let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the code that you use to write and read again?

Comment: Could you also specify the version of spark you are using?

Comment: This might help you but it's hard to say without more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297547/handling-empty-arrays-in-pyspark-optional-binary-element-utf8-is-not-a-group

Comment: Thank you all for your comments... The issue got resolved and it was related to different path used for read which I identified later. Parquet format is correct and is working fine.